# Rails 5.2 : Incorrect DB adapter being called by app. Why?

Tags: mysql, sqlite, spree, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I have a Spree application running locally and deployed to a remote server. Originally the app was running on both machines using the sqlite3 adapter. I've updated `database.yml` to use mysql2, created both local and remote MySQL databases and the app runs fine locally. The `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` files do not contain any reference to sqlite3, only mysql2.

On the remote machine it is possible to connect to the DB using `rails c` and I can confirm it is using the correct MySQL DB by pulling records.

I'm using the gems mysql2 '0.5.2' and rails '5.2.1'.

Remotely, the app crashes with `ActionView::Template::Error (uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLite3Adapter)`.

Why does the remote version seek the SQLite3Adapter?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was really simple - just delete the tmp/cache folder.